# Add several dependent lists to single HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, list

Recently I have been working on some project. It is a single page built in HTML and also contains several JS elements.

I use several lists in the page. the issue is that I have a dependent list which means that after selecting the value from the main list the second list displays relevant items. All works smoothly, however in the same page I have to add the same dependent list. the list is absolutely the same, just it is located in another section of this page.

Tee problem is that when I choose something from the first dependent list it affects the second dependent list located in other section. And when I choose value from second dependent list, nothing happens.

I changed the name, id of second list, but without result.

I am posting here the sample code of first list in the page, the JS code for dependent list.

Could you help me with this issue? the idea is to display same lists in different sections of the single HTML page, but both lists should work independently.

Code in HTML page in Body section:

```
      <select id="list" name="optone" size="1"
    onchange="setOptions(document.dependant_list.optone.options
    [document.dependant_list.optone.selectedIndex].value);">
    <option value=" " selected="selected"> </option>
    <option value="01 00 - Option 1">01 00 - Option 1</option>
    <option value="01 00 - Option 2">01 00 - Option 2</option>
    <option value="01 00 - Option 3">01 00 - Option 3</option>
    <option value="01 00 - Option 4">01 00 - Option 4</option>
    <option value="01 00 - Option 5">01 00 - Option 5</option>

</select>


<select id="list" name="opttwo" size="1">
<option value=" " selected="selected">Please, choose from main list first</option>
</select>
```

**JS code, in my case located in the external source:**

```
function setOptions(chosen) {
var selbox = document.dependant_list.opttwo;

selbox.options.length = 0;
if (chosen == "01 00 - Option 1") {
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new
Option('Dependent value 1');
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new
Option('Dependent value 2');
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new
Option('Dependent value 3');
}
if (chosen == "02 00 - Option 2") {
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new
Option('Dependent value 4');
}
if (chosen == "03 00 - Option 3") {
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new
Option('Dependent value 5');
}
if (chosen == "04 00 - Option 4") {
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new
Option('Dependent value 6');
}
if (chosen == "05 00 - Option 5") {
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new
Option('Dependent value 7');
}

}
```

Please write if any additional details are needed.

**Updated:**

```
<DIV ID="services"

 <select class="list" name="optone" size="1"
    onchange="setOptions(document.dependant_list.optone.options
    [document.dependant_list.optone.selectedIndex].value);">
    <option value=" " selected="selected"> </option>
    <option value="01 00 - Option 1">01 00 - Option 1</option>
    <option value="01 00 - Option 2">01 00 - Option 2</option>
    <option value="01 00 - Option 3">01 00 - Option 3</option>
    <option value="01 00 - Option 4">01 00 - Option 4</option>
    <option value="01 00 - Option 5">01 00 - Option 5</option>

</select>

 <select class="list" name="opttwo" size="1">
    <option value=" " selected="selected">Please, choose from main list first</option>
    </select>


</div>




<div id="fraud">

 <select class="list" name="optone" size="1"
    onchange="setOptions(document.dependant_list.optone.options
    [document.dependant_list.optone.selectedIndex].value);">
    <option value=" " selected="selected"> </option>
    <option value="01 00 - Option 1">01 00 - Option 1</option>
    <option value="01 00 - Option 2">01 00 - Option 2</option>
    <option value="01 00 - Option 3">01 00 - Option 3</option>
    <option value="01 00 - Option 4">01 00 - Option 4</option>
    <option value="01 00 - Option 5">01 00 - Option 5</option>


 <select class="list" name="opttwo" size="1">
    <option value=" " selected="selected">Please, choose from main list first</option>
    </select>

</select>

</div>
```

As you can see the lists are in the different DIVs, however they are the same, after changing ID to CLASS, they still mess up with each other :(

Comment: You have `id="list"` twice. You can only use IDs once.

Comment: FYI, you can simply use `setOptions(this.value)` instead of all that stuff.

Comment: So you have a bunch of lists on your page and some of them change the options in other lists. Something like list 1 changes options of list 2. And list 3 changes options of list 4. Is that correct? I'm not very clear on the relationships of the lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the mistake here is really simple - ID is meant to be unique - thus leaving you only one of which on each page.

You should use classes instead of IDs for multiple instances like this - change id="list" to class="list" (and also the CSS attached).